# Obtener valores fila seleccionada ListView

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, listview, webforms

Quiero obtener la información de una fila seleccionada de un `ListView` para pasarlos a un objeto con los mismos (y otros más) campos.
Intenté con SelectedItemTemplate (ya que SelectedItems no me aparece) pero no puedo indizarlo (o indexarlo?) porque no me deja.

Necesito hacer algo como esto:

```
obj.codigo = LitView.SelectedItem[0].toString();
obj.nombre = LitView.SelectedItem[1].toString();
```

Donde [0] seria el codigo del elemento seleccionado, [1] el nombre del mismo, ect.

Si sirve de algo, acá el código del ListView:

`

```
   <GroupTemplate>
        <tr runat="server">
            <td id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server"></td>
        </tr>
    </GroupTemplate>

    <LayoutTemplate>
        <table>
            <td runat="server" id="groupPlaceholder"></td>
        </table>
    </LayoutTemplate>


    <ItemTemplate>

        <td class="align text-center">
            <br />
            <asp:Label ID="codArt" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("CodArticulo_A") %>' Visible="false" />
            <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("Imagen_A") %>' runat="server" CommandName="eventoImageButton1" OnCommand="ImageButton1_Command" />
            <br />
            <asp:Label ID="nombreLibro" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Nombre_A") %>' />
            <br />
            <asp:Label ID="nombreAutor" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("NombreAutor") %>' />
            <br />
            $  
                <asp:Label ID="Precio" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("PrecioUnitario_A") %>' />
            <br />
            <asp:Button ID="addCarrito" runat="server" CssClass="btn" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Nombre_A") %>' Text="Agregar al carrito" OnCommand="addCarrito_Command"    />

        </td>

    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>`
```

Comment: Prueba con [`SelectedDataKey`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.selecteddatakey(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Acabo de hacer eso y me tira un `System.NullReferenceException`

Comment: Creo que tienes que poner los `DataKeyNames`. Mira el enlace que te puse, ahi tienes un ejemplo

Answer (score 2):

Cuando tu ListView está en modo Detail el item seleccionado solo se muestra en la primera columna, el resto de columnas tienes que accesar a ellas como SubItems

```
listView1.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[0].Text;
listView1.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[1].Text;
listView1.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[2].Text;
```

Comment: Estoy trabajando con asp.net, no con win forms. De cualquier forma, podrías explicarme un poquito más eso del modo Detail?

Comment: Mil disculpas, es cierto, no leí la parte de asp.net de tu pregunta. Esto solo aplica para WinForms. Es asp.net deberias de intentar con la funcion FindControl. Por ejemplo: `obj.codigo =((Label) LitView.Items(LitView.SelectedIndex).FindControl("codArt")).Text;`
El Detail al que me refería es solo un modo de View que tiene el control ListView de WinForms.

Comment: No tengo el `metodo SelectedItem`, sólo el `SelectedItemTemplate`..

Comment: si, había editado el comentario, la manera es `LitView.Items(LitView.SelectedIndex).FindControl("codArt")).‌​Text;`

Comment: No lo había visto, disculpá. Igualmente no me funciona: `No se puede utilizar como método el miembro 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListView.Items' no invocable `.

Comment: Ah claro es por los parentesís, mis disculpas:
`LitView.Items[LitView.SelectedIndex].FindControl("codArt")).‌​‌​Text;`

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55449/discussion-between-yamila-marucci-and-reekeecast).